# Why clearTimeout is not working in my code? javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, removechild, cleartimeout

I've got some issues with clearTimeout().

setTimeout() is working but when I close my notification I want setTimeout to stop working!

The think is that I don't know what in my function is not correct.

And when I close notification I got this on my console:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Thanks!

```
class Notification {
  addNotification() {

    let notificationContent = `Content <div onclick="notify.closeWindow(event)"></div>`;

    let notifyArea = document.createElement("div");
    notifyArea.classList.add("notification-area");

    let notification = document.createElement("div");
    notification.classList.add("notification");
    notification.innerHTML = notificationContent;

    const area = document.querySelector(".notification-area");

    let firstTimer;
    let secondTimer;

    if (!area) {
      document.body.appendChild(notifyArea);
      notifyArea.appendChild(notification);

      if (notification == null) {
        clearTimeout(firstTimer);
      } else if (notification) {
        firstTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          notifyArea.removeChild(notification);
        }, 10000);
      }
    } else {
      area.appendChild(notification);

      if (!notification) {
        clearTimeout(secondTimer);
      } else {
        secondTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          area.removeChild(notification);
        }, 10000);
      }
    }

  closeWindow(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your timers in the `closeWindow` or the `removeChild` function will be called after the node is already removed. Note that you have to make the timers to be properties of the class to be able to access them in the `closeWindow` function

```
class Notification {
  addNotification() {

    let notificationContent = `Content <div onclick="notify.closeWindow(event)"></div>`;

    let notifyArea = document.createElement("div");
    notifyArea.classList.add("notification-area");

    let notification = document.createElement("div");
    notification.classList.add("notification");
    notification.innerHTML = notificationContent;

    const area = document.querySelector(".notification-area");

    this.firstTimer;
    this.secondTimer;

    if (!area) {
      document.body.appendChild(notifyArea);
      notifyArea.appendChild(notification);

      if (notification == null) {
        clearTimeout(this.firstTimer);
      } else if (notification) {
        this.firstTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          notifyArea.removeChild(notification);
        }, 10000);
      }
    } else {
      area.appendChild(notification);

      if (!notification) {
        clearTimeout(this.secondTimer);
      } else {
        this.secondTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          area.removeChild(notification);
        }, 10000);
      }
    }

  closeWindow(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.firsTimer);
    clearTimeout(this.secondTimer);
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: I just added notification.remove() instead of notifyArea.removeChild(notification);

Comment: good but the best solution is to clear the timeout like in this answer. Please accept the answer. You can use `this.firstTimer = setTimeout(function...` so you can have access to the timers in the `closeWindow` function

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Please add that to your answer, it doesn't work without making the timer id a property